# how can i force the hover state off?

Tags: jquery, css, hover

I've got a text button with a :hover color change.  Clicking the button shrinks the div it sits within, and thus moves the button out from under the mouse cursor that clicked it.  Doing so leaves the button in the :hover state, so it doesn't change back to the non-hover color.  Is there any way I can force the button out of the hover state (since I know it won't be hovered on for sure at that moment)?

jsfiddle example here: http://jsfiddle.net/forgetcolor/vYjMv/6/

p.s.: i know on that jsfiddle example as soon as i move the mouse myself the state changes, but unfortunately on my own example it doesn't---not until i move over the button again.  i'm guessing this is because in my case what's left underneath the mouse cursor when the shrinking element moves is an iframe with a PDF in it (?)

Comment: Dont understand your question.. Can you explain with sample images, or more "detailed" sample?

Comment: look at the example.  move your mouse to the show/hide text 'button' in the result section.  click the button but don't move your mouse.  the color of the text stays in the hover state.  i want to know how to programmatically force the element's hover state off (or back to non-hover) when the thing is clicked to avoid this.

Comment: Here works correctly, like a hover, if I don't move mouse.. Text color on hover: red, on click and not move mouse: blue..

Comment: Works for me too.  I'm using Firefox 12 on Windows.

Comment: Why not use jQuery toggle to toggle show/hide? http://api.jquery.com/toggle/

Comment: guess i should have said i'm working in chrome, where it works as i describe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would not use a `:hover` selector in the CSS, but a `.hover` class instead. Then you can explicitly assign this class to `mouseover`/`mouseout`, and explicitly remove it when needed.

Does this solve your problem?

**UPDATE**

Suggestion: use jQuery's `$().hover()`.

Comment: doesn't fix the problem, at least in chrome: http://jsfiddle.net/forgetcolor/vYjMv/10/